# Why runningAppProcessInfo return always only one process?

Tags: android, kotlin

```
package com.locker

import android.app.ActivityManager
import android.app.Service
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Handler
import android.os.IBinder
import android.util.Log

class BackgroundService : Service() {
    private lateinit var mHandler: Handler
    private lateinit var mRunnable: Runnable

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder? {
        throw UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        mHandler = Handler()
        mRunnable = Runnable { checkApps() }
        mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 500)

        return Service.START_STICKY
    }

    private fun checkApps() {
        val am = getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as ActivityManager
        val runningAppProcessInfo = am.runningAppProcesses
        Log.d("backgroundService", runningAppProcessInfo.indices.toString())
        for (i in runningAppProcessInfo.indices) {
            Log.d("backgroundService", runningAppProcessInfo[i].processName)
            if (runningAppProcessInfo[i].processName == "com.android.settings") {
                //val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java).apply {}
                //startActivity(intent)
                Log.d("backgroundService", runningAppProcessInfo[i].processName)
            }
        }
        mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 500)
    }
}
```

Here is code of my service. Basicly I want to get list of running apps every 500ms but now I have got only one process (my app). I tried to open another app but still it show me only my app. What im doing wrong?

Comment: getRunningTasks(int) has been deprecated since API 21, for security reasons, what api are your targeting?

Comment: My minimum target is API 26

Comment: and your  targetSdkVersion? That's the one needed in order know what to use

Comment: minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 29

Comment: The best approach for api 29+ is to get the list of application processes; for each process, we check if it is in foreground and finally get the package name

Comment: I thought that my code doing that check

Comment: You are not, since you are using runningAppProcesses()

Comment: Can you show me how to change my code or do you have example what method to use?

Comment: I was wrong, all method are depreciated and my previous answer is not longer valid. [UsageStatsManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager) is the only option for now